# How to implement your own efficient OS listener?

Tags: java, multithreading, listener

How to create your own listener that listens to the OS efficiently in Java? For example like the ActionListener in Swing, that reacts to button clicks.

I want to make a program that logs the users clipboard, but I don't want to use a loop like this:

```
while (flag)
{
      Transferable t = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
            .getSystemClipboard()
            .getContents(null);

      if (t != null && t.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor))
        {
            try
            {
                String text = (String) t
                    .getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
                System.out.println(text);
            }
            catch (UnsupportedFlavorException e1)
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e1)
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

I want the processor only to work when the clipboard changed and not check every second if that is the case.

Secondly I found a Method that might work

```
    this.clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
         .getSystemClipboard();
    this.clipboard.addFlavorListener(new FlavorListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void flavorsChanged(FlavorEvent e)
        {
            // work with the clipboard contents
        }
    });
```

But still I need a strange while loop that consumes processor time to keep the program active.

I think that I should use wait and notfiy, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: If the available APIs aren't working the way you want, then you will need to investigate the native platform APIs themselves and link to through JNI/JNA